# PHP POST not being recieved by my API sent from Trading View Widget

Tags: php, post, tradingview-api

good morning everyone,

I am having some issues with while usiong TradingView Charts specifically the Save function..
it basically Sends a _GET and _POST request to mt custom build API.

the issue I am having is that the _POST is not being picked up by my code.
I am Presuming here that their code is fine as I cant see any other posts regarding this issue.

the POST request is being sent to:
example.com/1.0/chart?user=2&client=TradingGuru
Chart Data should then be picked up via the POST but it does not.

I have setup some tests As followed:

```
   if(isset($_GET)){
        $formattedGET = print_r($_GET, true);
        $formattedPOST = print_r($_POST, true);
        Send_email("API", "A Request has been recieved : GET = $formattedGET <br /> POST = $formattedPOST" );
    }
```

this then sends me an email that looks like so:

```
A Request has been recieved : GET = Array (
    [client] => TradingGuru
    [user] => 2
)
 <br /> POST = Array
(
)
```

I have not had an issue with any other more simple POST methods on the rest of my site and the only thing I can think its that my File/Folder Layout is as so:

www/1.0/charts/index.php which when I test the GET functions on chrome auto corrects to : example.com/1.0/charts/?client=devtg&user=2

any ideas on this one would be very much appreciated as I feel like I have been banging my head against a brick wall for some time now.

Extended:
Still Having issues and have narrowed it down to something my side now,
I have setup a simple POST from JS (which takes a Js Object and JSONParse it) :

```
var JSONs = JSON.stringify(savedWidgetContent)
let response = await new Promise(resolve => {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", chart_storageURL+"/0.1/charts/?client=devtg&user=2"+uid);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.onload = function(e) {
     resolve(xhr.response);
};
xhr.onerror = function () {
    resolve(undefined);
    console.error("** An error occurred during the XMLHttpRequest");
};
    xhr.send(JSONs);
});
```

I then have a stripped back PHP code as below:

```
   if(isset($_POST)){
        $formattedPOST = print_r($_POST, true);
        $formatServer = print_r($_SERVER, true);
        $File_get = file_get_contents('php://input');
        Send_email("API - POST", "A Request has been recieved : POST = 
        $formattedPOST , $File_get" );
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
```

However my Testing Script keeps sending me the email with

> POST = Array ( )

Comment: This "example.com/1.0/chart?user=2&client=TradingGuru only shows us the $_GET... can you show the post itself ? the curl or whatever?

Comment: You can also always setup a https://webhook.site/ hook link and send the post over there... you will see immediately if post data is being sent and how... perhaps it's in the body...

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for their request? You're absolutely sure it's a POST request? Since you already have a test script to send you e-mails, could I suggest that you in that e-mail also include the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` (to verify that it's POST) and perhaps even `file_get_contents('php://input')` (in case the data is submitted in a format that's not parsed into the `$_POST` variable)?

Comment: @olafmoriarty - I will add those parameters now I have added detection for Just POST and Just GET and it sending 2 emails to my but again the POST array is blank. Link to the Wiki on git, it may be loicked for you though as its on request only - https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Saving-and-Loading-Charts#what-is-a-chart-layout

Comment: @olafmoriarty Incase the git is locked for you here as an Excert for the function I am using : SAVE CHART
POST REQUEST: charts_storage_url/charts_storage_api_version/charts?client=client_id&user=user_id

name: name of the chart
content: content of the chart
symbol: chart symbol (example, AA)
resolution: chart resolution (example, 1D)
RESPONSE: JSON Object

status: ok or error
id: unique integer identifier of the chart (example, 9163)

Comment: @Shlomtzion - not as simple as that as the JS from the Trading View Takes SiteURL/APIR NUMBER/  then sends the POSt/GET requests there.

Comment: @olafmoriarty - OK, so I have added Everything the if isset(POST) is generating this email reposnce:A Request has been recieved : POST = Array (
)
 SERVER_REQUEST: GET File Contents:

Comment: Okay, they're definitely sending you a GET request, then, which I'm pretty sure means there can be no POST data embedded in it. Meaning the error lies not in your script, but in the request they send. (Since they're sending it as a json I assume it will be put in php://input and not in $_POST, but as long as the request type is GET no post data is coming through anyway.) My best advice would be to take a step back and examine any configuration you have for the request they send you.

Comment: @olafmoriarty - Thanks Ola, Im seeing some return Data on the JS side that returns a large array of points on the graph so Im presumign they expect me to manually Encode the array and send it myself (which I am currently working on. Ill post a Answer to the question if I ge tit working as the Documentation does not suggest that this is the case.

Comment: @olafmoriarty - I have updated my Question above, still no ideas as to why the thing wont pickup the POST data I am sending it.

Answer (score 2):

Both requests are not the same request, they're likely made one after the other. So when the POST request is made, your `if(isset($_GET))` condition is false (since it's not a GET request, but a POST request).

Try having two conditions (or just removing the condition entirely).

For example:

```php
if(isset($_GET)){
    $formattedGET = print_r($_GET, true);
    Send_email("API", "A GET Request has been recieved : $formattedGET" );
}
elseif(isset($_POST)) {
    $formattedPOST = print_r($_POST, true);
    Send_email("API", "A POST Request has been recieved : $formattedPOST" );
}
```

Comment: aaaah OK ill give that a go now thanks!

Comment: @Chris_livermore Let me know how it goes! :)

Comment: @Saphire Still not displaying an array but it is picking up both the POSt and GET {POST = Array (
)

}